# Android backup over wifi without SD-Card or USB-Cable

Tags: backup, android

I'm trying to do a full android backup of a phone with a broken USB-port and no SD-Card.

I first attempted to follow this tutorial [[GUIDE] How to make a nandroid backup directly to your computer without using sdcard](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1818321). However it failed at the command `/system/xbin/busybox nc -l -p 5555 -e /system/xbin/busybox dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0` which gave me the following error `nc: bind: Address already in use`.

Then I tried this command `adb shell 'dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0' > mmcblk0.img` to get the backup to my PC. This, however, only wrote `/dev/block/mmcblk0: cannot open for read: Permission denied` to the file. Thus, I tried installing *adb insecure* but then I couldn't connect to my Android device via adb over WiFi anymore (see [FIXED: Can't connect to adb over wifi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790445/fixed-cant-connect-to-adb-over-wifi))

Any ideas on how I can get a backup of my phone to my PC?

Comment: If the port is in use simply try another?

Comment: I did try to use port 5556 but the same error occurred.
Does the error message of nc mean, the port is in use?

Comment: Hi Marc, please remove the solution (and solved) from your question and add it as answer, which you should accept to show it resoved your issue. SE- Sites are Question / Answer sites.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help in using Super User and thanks to Daniel B for pointing me towards the solution. I removed my solution from the question and added it as an answer. I'll accept it as the right answer once it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Daniel B. the port was actually the problem. When using adb over WiFi one has to use another port for the *nc* command. The following commands allowed me to backup my phone.

On my Android phone I issued the following commands.

```
su
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

Next on my PC I had to use:

```
adb forward tcp:5556 tcp:5556
adb shell
su
/system/xbin/busybox nc -l -p 5556 -e /system/xbin/busybox dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0
```

And in another terminal:

```
adb forward tcp:5556 tcp:5556
cd /path/to/store/the/backup
nc 127.0.0.1 5556 | pv -i 0.5 > mmcblk0.raw
```

(Note the use of the ports **5555** and **5556** in the commands.)